# Visual Studio for mac broken(doesn't compile)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

After an energy fault, my mac mini was shut down inappropriately and now I simply can't work anymore with VS for mac(8.6.7 build 2). If I add a new class file or any new xaml tag, giving it a name and reference it on code behind, VS doesn't links these references. This already happened other times but this time it doesn't compiles the project also.

```
Error CS0103: The name 'MinhaAnimacao' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) (MyProject)
```

Everything that was compiled before that works fine, so if I compile without new elements it pass ok and VS finds its references as expected.

I was using VS 8.4, have updated to 8.6.7, but no success. Also tried to delete bin/obj from main folder(not on android/ios folders).

**EDIT:**

Just have noticed that VS broke the project files. With other projects it works fine. Do you guys know how to fix project files?

Comment: Try uninstalling and re-installing.  If software stopped working because of a power failure it's likely either a hardware glitch or something was written inappropriately to a disk, corrupting a file.  An uninstall/re-install might fix that

Comment: @Flydog57 just noticed that the problem is that VS have broken the project files. With other projects it works fine. Do you know how to fix project files?

Comment: Reconstruct it manually using another project file as a template. It's just XML. Or grab a copy from source control.

Comment: How does it "break" project files?

Comment: If it's not a large project, create a new project (with the same settings) in a new location and copy the source over from your old project.  Then add the copied source to your new project.  Another (less sure) option, if your code is in source control, compare your current code to what is there and try fix things manually.  It's not really Visual Studio's fault that those files are "broken" - power failures during disk writes can do bad things.